# Creating two instances of a particular servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have query , that If I mentioning the web.xml for my servlet application such as shown below ..

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>AuthenticationServlet</servlet-name>
<display-name>AuthenticationServlet</display-name>
<servlet-class>com.trading.AuthenticationServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>AuthorizationServlet</servlet-name>
<display-name>AuthorizationServlet</display-name>
<servlet-class>com.trading.AuthorizationServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now I want for AuthenticationServlet servlet container should create two instances of it , How I will do that , Please advise

Comment: Any specific reason to have two instances?

Comment: @thinksteep I was doing research on that..!!  :)

Answer (score 5):

You can just define multiple servlet instances using different `<servlet>` entries in `web.xml` pointing to the same servlet class.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AuthorizationServlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.trading.AuthorizationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AuthorizationServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.trading.AuthorizationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

You'll only need to map them on different URL patterns.

That said, I have the strong impression that you're looking in the completely wrong direction while looking for a solution for the particular functional requirement which you didn't tell anything about in your question. In a properly designed servlet web application, there should usually be no need to have more than one instance of the servlet. If you for example need to store user-specific information, use the HTTP session for that. To learn how servlets work and how they are to be used, read [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909)